# i have a problem when i want to loop my code, it will repeat loop even user input is true

Tags: java, swing

problem loop will repeat again and again even user input true

```
int D1 = 1;
    do{
    String N6 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Working Hours for Week 2","Working Hours",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        int D = Integer.parseInt(N6);
            if (D < 40 && (stat.equals("Full Time"))) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Full Timers Working Hours must be between 40 - 90 Hours !","Error",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                D++;
            }
    } while ( D1 <= 1 );
```

Comment: You never change `D1`, it's always 1.

Comment: Dear Zafri, please add some description to your post. posting code cannot help you to settle your issue.

Comment: An upvote I give to your post just for your good manner about editing. Thanks.

Comment: @Guy wdym by that? i dont understand

Comment: @ZafriWahab Your loop condition is `D1 <= 1`. You initialize it to 1 before the loop but never change it so `D1` will be bigger than 1.

Comment: @Guy so what should i change? D1 > 1 ?

Comment: @ZafriWahab This is up to you, I don't know what you are trying to do. But you need to change the value of `D1` inside the loop or it will run infinitely (or just once if the condition is `false` from the start, but then you don't need a loop at all).

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).